# beautifulsoup unable to extract href link

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, phantomjs

So i am using selenium , phantomjs as my webdriver, and beautifulsoup.
currently i want to extract all the links which are underneath the attribute title.
[The site i want to extract](http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/#/?category=FA&sub_category=FA1&alphabetical=All&company=9695)

However, it seems to be not picking up these links at all ! What is going on ?

```
# The standard library modules
import os
import sys
import re

# The wget module
import wget

# The BeautifulSoup module
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# The selenium module
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


def getListLinks(link):
    #setup drivers
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true'])
    driver.get(link) # load the web page
    src = driver.page_source 

    #Get text and split it
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'html5lib')
    print soup
    links = soup.find_all('a')
    print links    

    driver.close()

getListLinks("http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/#/?category=FA&sub_category=FA1&alphabetical=All&company=9695&date_from=01/01/2012&date_to=31/12/2016")
```

Here is an example of a link i want to extract

```
<a href="/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/5455245">Quarterly rpt on consolidated results for the financial period ended 31/03/2017</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

What I really don't understand is why you are mixing beautifullsoup with selenium. Selenium has it's own api for extract dom element. You don't need to bring BS4 into the picture. Besides BS4 can only work with static HTML and ignores dynamically generated HTML which your selenium instance is capable of handling.

Just do

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
```

Comment: ohhh okay. i'm actually not so familiar with how to use these libraries yet xP . thanks!
tho i found out that if you try to load the link , it removes all the additional filters and loads the main link http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/#/?category=all
if you try to load it once on your browser, it shows the main page first, but on the second reload(copy paste the link again on your browser url), it shows you the site with the filter's i have chosen. any idea's how to make it not do that?

Comment: That's to do with the cookies, and sounds like a different question (because there is no mention of filters here). Once we get this sorted out, please post another question and I will be happy to have a go at it.

Comment: here you go. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44448137/python-selenium-site-urls-filter-configuration-keeps-resetting

Answer (score 0):

You want the links under the title column which is the 4th column of the table. You can use an nth-of-type selector to restrict to table cells (td elements) within 4 column of each row of target table. A wait condition is added to ensure elements are present.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

d = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/#/?category=all'
d.get(url)
links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in WebDriverWait(d, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tr  td:nth-of-type(4) a')))]
print(links)
d.quit()
```